# Is it possible to outline a pie piece using plotly.js?

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, plotly

Suppose I'm just using the [basic pie chart](https://plot.ly/javascript/pie-charts/#basic-pie-chart) from plotly's documentation:

[image: basic pie chart]

```js
var data = [{
  values: [19, 26, 55],
  labels: ['Residential', 'Non-Residential', 'Utility'],
  type: 'pie'
}];

var layout = {
  height: 400,
  width: 500
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

I want to know how I can outline a specific slice. I'm envisioning something like this:

[image: slice highlighted]

I don't see anything in the plotly.js documentation that suggests how this might be done, which is why I'm asking here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the width of the line for each of the parts (in the marker).

```
marker: {
    line: {
        color: '#444',
        width: [0, 5, 0]
    },
}
```

Here is an example:

```js
var data = [{
  values: [19, 26, 55],
  labels: ['Residential', 'Non-Residential', 'Utility'],
  type: 'pie',
  marker: {
    line: {
        color: '#444',
        width: [0, 5, 0]
      },
  }
}];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

```html
<!-- Plotly.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- Numeric JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeric/1.2.6/numeric.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
```

Comment: Awesome! This appears to be exactly what I need. I appreciate it.